# How do I list the output of ps -U root -u root -eo pid in a single line seperated by comma's

Tags: linux

when I execute the cmd ps -U root -u root -eo pid I get the output in multiple lines

Eg:
    1
    2
    3
    4

I would like to see the output in one line as 1,2,3,4,5 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way is

```
ps -U root -u root -eo pid | tr -s "\n" ","
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using the ps -U root -u root -eo pid | tr -s \n , . No quotes and it makes one hell of a differernce

Answer (score 0):

No need external command

```
var=$(ps -U root -u root -eo pid )
echo ${var//$'\n'/,}
```